# Working with GUI's in java

Tags: java, swing

I really need some help i've tried many scenarios of code and none seem to deliver the outcome.

I would like to produce a GUI where the Question is on one line and centered and the possible answers are on the next line centered too. I've produced this code - my thinking was make a Box Layout and add two flow layouts inside the box layout one for the question and one for the possible answers

Comment: Why are you extending a `JFrame` and creating an object of it? Do one or the other, not both, however I prefer the object one. Also don't use `setSize(1500,900);`, instead use `myWindow.pack()` and let Swing determine the size of your window. *I have no pasted the full method only the parts I think are required* Pasting a [Runnable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would get you more and better answers (not your whole code, but the minimum that we can copy-paste and see the same issue as you).

Comment: What specifically is your question? If I understood it correctly, you want your panels completely centered inside the parent-panel, both horizontally and vertically? If yes, a standard `GridBagLayout()` containing the panel would do fine.

Comment: I created a runnable class for the problem, I dont fully understand how the GridBagLayout works, i have tried to use it and have been unsuccessful. I want my layout to be something like this:https://gyazo.com/3cbab414b1859e7f5dddc26fc5c2f62a

Comment: class is here http://pastebin.com/pwMwqBfn

Comment: @Blueaddiction you should paste your code here on Stack Overflow not on external sites such as pastebin. Add it here please

Answer (score 4):

This behavior is correct as you are using [FlowLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html).

> The FlowLayout class puts components in a row, sized at their
>   preferred size. If the horizontal space in the container is too small
>   to put all the components in one row, the FlowLayout class uses
>   multiple rows.If the container is wider than necessary for a row of
>   components, the row is, by default, centered horizontally within the
>   container.

Use any other layout such as SpringLayout or GridBagLayout.

Comment: @Frakcool -  I wont be able to give a runnable exmaple as I'm using multiple classes i've created for this to work. the code is quite complicated and ill take  a look at gridbaglayout if i need help ill post here thanks

Comment: @Blueaddiction You should've posted this in the comments underneath the question, not under this answer. Anyway, a [mcve] is not meant to be your full code / all classes. It is meant to be a short, runnable example (just one class) which reproduces the problem and in which you took some effort to make. You really would just have needed to make an example with labels and buttons without any functionality, since it's a layout question.